# Magento 1.9: How to Add Product Using SOAP Api?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to api. Can anyone guide how to add product using SOAP api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to add product using soap api.

```
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl().'api/soap/?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

// If some stuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

// get attribute set
$attributeSets = $client->call($session, 'product_attribute_set.list');
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);


$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], 'product_sku', array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => 'Product name',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
)));

var_dump ($result);
```

You can add this code in any controller and then call that controller action in frontend. Your product will be added.

Comment: I am getting this error - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/magento/api/soap/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity

Comment: Replace 

$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

with 

$url = Mage::getBaseUrl().'api/soap/?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I have enabled extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini file, then that problem got solved. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting access denied for $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); How to create apiUser and apiKey in magento 1.9?

Comment: The tutorial isn't completely what you want, but it covers your "how to create an API user" question: https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/administration/596-step-by-step-create-a-magento-api-user

Comment: @ArjenMiedema - thanks - I have gone through the tutorial :)